# Custom footcite for @inreference type

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, footcite

I'm using `biblatex` with `@inreference` subtype for entries like online dictionaries. It's convenient that only the cross-referenced element appears in the bibliography. But when `@inreferences` are footciting in the text, they are only dinstiguished by a parenthized letter.

[image: Default footcite output]

When `\footfullcite` is used, things are getting better with the name and the url of the article:

[image: Default footfullcite output]

But it still lacks the title extracted from the cross-referenced element, and I'd like to only use the `\footcite` command: is this possible to customize this one according to the `@inreference` entry type?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=verbose-trad1,
    citestyle=authoryear-ibid,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inreference{WiktionaryAxis,
    crossref = {Wiktionary},
    title = {Axis},
    url = {https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/axis\#Latin}
}
@inreference{WiktionaryAssula,
    crossref = {Wiktionary},
    title = {Assula},
    url = {https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/assula\#la}
}
@online{Wiktionary,
    author = {{Wikimedia Foundation}},
    title = {Wiktionnaire},
    url = {https://fr.wiktionary.org}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

This is the first\footfullcite{WiktionaryAxis} and the second inreference\footfullcite{WiktionaryAssula}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: The MWE does not use `biblatex-chicago` as the text suggests. Is that intended? (Though the general approach will be similar, the solution will very much depend on the style you are actually using.) In any case `style=verbose-trad1, citestyle=authoryear-ibid,` is an odd combination (in fact it is equivalent to `citestyle=authoryear-ibid, bibstyle=authortitle,`). It will give you author-year citations, but the bibliography will effectively be author-title.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Yes, I forgot that I've switched back to `@biblatex` because I've found it simpler to create new driver (I need for a custom `movie` type with lots of custom fields, but this looks to me as another problem). But I don't really know why I'm using `style=verbose-trad1, citestyle=authoryear-ibid,` rather than `citestyle=authoryear-ibid, bibstyle=authortitle,`… indeed it seems to make the same result, is it better? (I am quite a begginer at biblatex but using it a lot for my Ph. D)

Comment: `citestyle=authoryear-ibid, bibstyle=authortitle,` is not really better than `style=verbose-trad1, citestyle=authoryear-ibid,`, it's just a little clearer. That said, combining authoryear and authortitle in that way is odd in any case. I'd just go with `style=authoryear-ibid,`

Comment: OK, thanks for the advice. But it does not really solve the question I have asked…

Comment: That is true, but since the solution depends on the style you use, we need to fix that first.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help! To meet the requirements of my university, even if it is a bit strange, I have to stick with `bibstyle=authortitle` that I will use with `citestyle=authoryear-ibid` to follow your advice.